# ORDER BY with TOP 100 PERCENT clause not working properly on the outer query. Replacing UNION with UNION ALL has effect on ORDERING of results

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have the below code:

```
select levelname from (
SELECT top 100 percent levelname, levelnum from CTE where 2>1 order by levelnum
UNION 
select distinct TOP 100 PERCENT PL.LevelNumAndName, pl.levelnum Level from Pyramid_level pl join Pyramid_unit pu on 
pl.levelnum = pu.levelnum and pl.clientnum = pu.clientnum
where pl.clientnum in ('001000', '000043') and 2 = 1
order by PL.levelnum
)A
```

*CTE is just a CTE which I am leaving out because I don't think is necessary. It has the requisite columns.*

If you look at the Last snippet, you would see that the portion after `UNION` has the below in `WHERE` clause:

```
and 2 = 1
```

So obviously this should not be executing. But below is my observation:

1. If I remove the part after `UNION`, the results are coming properly sorted.
2. If I keep that part(which should not be executing), the results are not correctly sorted.
3. If I keep that part and replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`, it seems that`ORDER BY` clause is effective again.

Someone please help me in understanding what's happening here!

**EDIT:** UNION and UNION ALL are with respect to the code I pasted, NOT inside CTE. CTE is just a plain select with the columns `levelname` and `levelnum` in it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. It is *not* responsible for the issue. Some confidential bit of code in it, that's why had to leave it out.

Comment: The **only** way to guarantee the order of results is to have an `ORDER BY` clause on the *outermost* query. That's it. Anything else is just programming by superstition and luck. The `TOP 100 PERCENT` "trick" is a kludge that works by coincidence, sometimes. Stop trying to make it work.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Sorry, I changed it

Comment: ORDER BY inside an UNION wont work even if the second part has an impossible condition,you need ORDER BY outside the UNION

Comment: @Mihai, @Damien : It seems to work if I replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`. Is that a coincidence?

Comment: @SouravA: `UNION` replaces duplicates `UNION ALL` not. The former is a set operation where the order is never guaranteed, the latter is a simple _Concat_.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - does that mean the order is somewhere "lost" `while` the engine searches for duplicates? Or `ORDER BY` never really works if it is NOT in the outermost query?

Comment: Yes. `ORDER BY` within subqueries is only *defined* to allow `TOP` to be well defined. A smart enough optimizer will realize that, when asked for `TOP 100 PERCENT`, it already knows that all rows will be part of the result so it can save itself the effort of performing any sorting.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Aha! That makes sense. But I wonder why the order changes if I instead have a `UNION ALL`

Comment: Until you place an `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost query, the answer is always that the results are returned in whatever order was most convenient for the server to perform its processing in. There's no guarantee that the results will be returned in the "same" order the next time the query is executed - either because the server has been updated in some way, or the distribution of data has changed, or the amount of available resources are different.

Comment: It seems to work is a good choice of words.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. Lesson learnt. You could probably add this as an answer if you want.